# Got wrong record for GROUP TOPIC PARTITION even after seeking to offset OFFSET

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm using Spark Streaming and suddenly I get this message when it tries to stream a topic. How can I skip this error?

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Got wrong record for GROUP TOPIC 109 even after seeking to offset 754809
at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:228)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:194)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:462)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438)
at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:222)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:988)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:979)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:919)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:979)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:697)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
```

Comment: Getting the same issue? any luck on finding the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an actual answer but didn't fit in the comment. Also, it is not a fix just work around.

Spark holds offsets as well and checks the integrity when consumes messages. It happens rarely that the offset state held in Spark  Streaming API doesn't match with what Kafka is holding. You can check the integrity of the offsets:

```
kafka-simple-consumer-shell --broker-list BROKER:9092 --clientId GROUP_ID --offset 752000 --print-offsets --max-messages 1000 --topic TOPIC | grep offset
```

Here, 752000 is an offset close but before the failing one, you see in the exception.

You can iterate over the output and see if the offsets are in order in Kafka.

However, in our case, the offsets in Kafka was just fine. We had an outage in Kafka and we had to recover by rebuilding logs. So, the approach we took was just skipping offsets to a point the state of Spark Streaming matches with Kafka.

In order to achieve that, we used kt tool as

```
kt group -brokers BROKER:9092 -topic TOPIC -group GROUP_ID -partitions 113 -reset 753000
```

Here, partition 113 is the one that has the offset problem (you can find it from exception) and 753000 is a possible offset that you guess it should be fine afterward. Sometimes, you need to repeat the process and restart your job to get to a point that everything is fine.

This process is completely experimental because the message doesn't tell you which offset is missing. Hence, based on your requirement to how much data to lose is OK, you can select a number before or after the offset mentioned in the log. For example, if offset 752900 is printed in the log message, you could skip the error by setting it to 752800 (faulty offset is before) or you have to set it to something earlier like 752950. In latter, it skips 50 messages.